# Images are not displayed in IE

Tags: security, browser, response-headers

Images are not displayed in IE8 and above after using X-content-type options. It works perfectly in Chrome, FF and IE7. I set the contentType as "image/png. I can't find a possible solution.

Does "nosniff" affect the display of images?

Comment: Show your relevant code to help reproduce the issue.

Comment: The header should be `Content-Type: image/png` (without the `s`)

Comment: sorry that was a mistype. image/png doesn't work either.

Comment: What does this have to do with Java or even JSP's?  It's browser related.

Comment: Thank you john16384. Could you please tell me what could be done? I get a red cross in place of the image.

Comment: Use F12/Developer Tools and inspect the network status for this element.